# Memory usage of a recursive array in Haskell

Tags: haskell, memory, dynamic-programming

I have a dynamic programming algorithm and I find my Haskell implementation very satisfying, as it allows me to define the master array recursively, like so:

```
fill :: Int -> Int -> Entry
fill 0 0 = Entry Origin 0.0
fill 0 j = ...
fill i 0 = ...
fill i j = f m i j

m :: Array (Int, Int) Entry
m = listArray dims [fill i j | (i, j) <- range dims]
```

where `f` is a moderately complex function referring back to the main array `m`. The `Entry` type is just a `Double` with a small annotation.

The data itself is quite large, and `m` ends up having on the order of 100M entries. The algorithm is still blazing fast, but it uses ~25GB RAM in the process. From reading around I understand that this is because it keeps around the full computation of the array entries instead of the final value, but if I switched to unboxed arrays, I could not define them recursively like in the example above.

Is there a way to have a cake (low memory footprint) and eat it (recursive definition)?

Comment: According to your data, it consumes roughly 250B / entry. Perhaps you could try improving that by making your `Entry` type stricter, e.g. by adding strictness annotation and/or unpacking. You can't avoid the boxing of `Entry` itself and use an unboxed array, but you probably can remove boxing from the components of `Entry`. How is that type defined?

Comment: Are you definitely using the entire matrix for your computation, or will there be some unevaluated entries?  A lot?

Comment: Would it be okay with you if you used 25GB temporarily -- e.g. during a precomputation phase at program startup or perhaps even before -- as long as the algorithm itself uses less during its run?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies.  @chi `data Entry = Entry Source Double`, `data Source = Origin | Left | Right | Top | Bottom`. So super simple. I believe that unboxing the `Double` part could help, because that's the recursively defined part.  @luqui I'd estimate that maybe half of the entries are actually used, and memory profiling supports that.  @DanielWagner I'm curious what you have in mind. In principle, 25 GB at any stage is a bit heavy, since I'd like to eventually run this on smaller machines, but I'm definitely listening.

Comment: I'd definitely try `data Entry = Entry {-# UNPACK #-} !Source {-# UNPACK #-} !Double` for such a basic type. Don't forget to turn on optimizations with `-O` (and to avoid GHCi for measuring performance)

Comment: @chi Thanks - I just ran your suggestion. I can't say for sure that it didn't help, but it did run out of memory on my 16GB laptop. So while it's good to know this trick, and it may have shaved a significant amount off the footprint, it's not a silver bullet (I guess that instinctively I'm hoping to be on the order of what this array "actually" needs, ie. ~1GB).

Comment: @Marek What I have in mind is this: as a precomputation pass, on a beefy machine, use your pretty definition above. Then freeze your boxed array into an unboxed array, which should fit in ~1.5GB or so by my calculations, and serialize to disk. Deserialize into a similar 1.5GB memory footprint on the weaker machine. With enough shenanigans, you may even be able to make this happen via mmap so that you get the OS' excellent memory management to take care of fetching only the parts you read from disk, but you can probably get quite far without those shenanigans.

Comment: @Marek Of course, a much simpler solution is to have your cake but don't eat it; use mutable unboxed arrays to build in the first place, then (unsafe)freeze once. You won't have to ship a 1.5GB file, at the cost of recomputing the entire array on startup and having to choose a correct order to compute array elements in.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for these ideas. I think that if push comes to shove, I'll just give up on the nice definition. Certainly in production, if and when it comes to that, but for now I'm just going to live with the RAM footprint I guess. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I got reasonable results with unboxed mutable array, like so:

```
import Data.Array.ST as UM
import Control.Monad (forM_)

mbounds = ((0,0), (..., ...))
m = UM.runSTUArray $ do
    arr <- UM.newArray_ mbounds
    let set = UM.writeArray arr
    let get = UM.readArray arr
    let fill (0, 0) = do set (0, 0) 0.0
        fill (i, 0) = do top <- get (i-1, 0)
                         set (i, 0) (f top)
        fill (0, j) = do ...
        fill (i, j) = do ...
    forM_ (UM.range mbounds) fill
    return arr
```

Still quite a bit more RAM gets hogged than I would like (~4GB), but it's a huge improvement and I suspect that after I re-run the profiler, I'm going to find ways to cut it down further.